# Cufon font replacement: How do you define "hoverables"

Tags: html, css, embedded-fonts, font-replacement

With Cufon font replacement, you can define hover states like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Cufon.replace('h1', {
     hover: true,
     hoverables: { strong: true, em: true }
     });
   });
</script>
```

**Is it possible to describe specific CSS classes for the *hoverables*?**

(I have a JQuery accordion menu that is behaving strangely, and I think defining these hoverables will solve the problem. If it helps at all, [here is the menu](http://www.gaelen.co.za/example6/)).

Comment: Have you considered @font-face instead? It's much more simpler than Cufon and is supported by almost all browsers nowadays (even IE6).

Comment: Thanks RoToRa. Yes, I have been using @font-face, but I find the FOUT (flash of unformatted text) more severe. Also, I think the licensing on some fonts that I want to use prohibit uploading of the font to a public server. Cufon renders the font into a different format which is harder to reverse engineer and which some font EULA's haven't caught up with yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cufon('h1', {    
  fontWeight: 'normal',    
  hover: { fontWeight: 'bold' }
});
```

This should work i guess

Answer (score 1):

You can define hover styles on [Cufon](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API) targets by passing an object to the `hover` property, not to the `hoverables` property like you have attempted in your question:

```
Cufon.replace('h1', {
   hover: { fontWeight: bold, textDecoration: italic }
});
```

The `hoverables` property is available to allow you to enable hover state on elements other than `a` tags - Cufon defaults to only enabling hover styles on anchor tags because IE6 did not support anything else, but you can choose to enable support for other elements using the following syntax:

```
Cufon.replace('h1', {
   hover: { fontWeight: bold, textDecoration: italic },
   hoverables: { a: true, img : true }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dexter. I have some pre-defined CSS styles (that are used by some JScript). Is it possible to name these styles in `hoverables:` so that they get applied to the hover text, rather than specifying specific individual style atributes?

Comment: I guess something like this:
`Cufon.replace('h1', {
   hover: { #hoverstyle1 },
   hoverables: { a: true, img : true }
});`

Oh, I see it says I need to notify you of my reply by doing this: @Dexter